# Using "of" with numbers

Tags: prepositions

I am confused about using "of" with numbers. When do numbers come before or after the "of"?

> ***After the "of"***
>
> A bill of £42.50
>
> A height of 10 metres
>
> A weight of 225 kilograms
>
> ***Before the "of"***
>
> 2 kilograms of apples
>
> Millions of insects
>
> 12-mile stretch of fine sand

So, I wonder which of the following examples are true ?

1- 5 inch screen

2- 5 inch of screen

3- A screen of 5 inch

1'- 2 kilograms dumbbell

2'- 2 kilograms of dumbbell

3'- A dumbbell of 2 kilograms

Answer (score 2):

Some of your examples are valid but they would be used in different contexts. Also, some need to be plural and others singular.

Television and computer screens are measured diagonally. A **5 inch screen** would measure 5 inches from the bottom left corner to the top right corner.

When we use a number ahead of a measure, we keep the measure singular. For example, a 10-kilometre run, a 20-pound weight, a 5-litre can.

Another way to say a **5-inch screen** would be **a screen of 5 inches**. In this case it has to be plural - not **5 inch**.

Someone who needed to mend a hole in a mosquito screen might require **five inches of screen** to cover the hole. To be precise, that would be either 5 square inches or, more likely, 5 inches square. Again, note the plural **inches**.

A dumbbell weighing 2kg is a **2 kilogram dumbbell**. (Kilogram used in the singular here is a noun adjunct, acting as an adjective, like the examples above.)

If you were delivering a dumbbell in parts to somebody's door, you might say **I have 2 kilograms of dumbbell** for you - although this is an unusual way of putting it.

And a 2kg dumbbell can be described as **a dumbbell of 2 kilograms** although most people would simply call it a **2 kilogram dumbbell**.

It's a matter of context.

Comment: Thanks, one more question : Should I say "2-kilogram dumbbell" or "2 kilogram dumbbell" ? Are both okay ?

Comment: "When we use a number ahead of a measure, we keep the measure singular. For example, a 10-kilometre run, a 20-pound weight, a 5-litre can." Can we use this rule with plural nouns ? For example : "500-page books" or "5-litre cans"

Comment: Yes, the same rule applies to plural nouns - 200 kilogram lions. Measures are generally abbreviated after numbers. (https://abbreviations.yourdictionary.com/articles/measurement-abbreviations.html).  When using the measure fully written, I should not use a hyphen, just a space. Where abbreviations are concerned, I have seen variations such as 20km, 20-km and 20 km. This may be a matter of style rather than of any rule. Others may be able to give you better guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

With countable nouns in the plural and with uncountable nouns, we use:

- X measure (in the plural) of Y

e.g. 2 kilograms of apples / 2 liters of water

With countable nouns in the singular, we can use:

- (a) X-measure (in the singular) Y

or

- (a) Y of X measure (in the plural)

e.g. a five-inch screen / a screen of five inches

Comment: If I want to convert "books over 500 pages" to this form which one would be correct ? "500 pages of books"(that sounds wrong to me) or "500-page books"

Comment: You can say "books of (over) 500 pages" or "500-page books".

Comment: Thanks :) lastly I am allowed to use this form "2-kilogram apples"

Comment: No. Pay attention to the letters X and Y I used. X stands for a number, and Y for the thing being measured. You should say "2 kilograms of apples". "2-kilogram apples" would mean "apples each weighing 2 Kg"!